# how to align the memory in c++ when passing in Struct

Tags: c++, memory-alignment

My need is to aligned the memory by 4096, since this is the requirement of the dll I am using.
so previously it was no problem since just I used to have

```
char *mem_buff = (char *)_aligned_malloc(sizeof(char)*XX, 4096);
```

but now since I want to share the memory using struct (for the reason of using the threads) hence I am stuck with what and how to do?

```
struct g_thread_param {
int thr_cnt ; 
int indv_cnt ;
char mem_buff[XX]; //what to do to aligne this to 4096
} ;
```

thanks

Comment: Can `mem_buff` be a separate piece of memory from the struct?

Comment: You can put the `mem_buff` member first in your structure, then allocate aligned memory for `g_thread_param` using your old technique, iff `X` is a compile time constant.  If not, then you could have `g_thread_param` store a pointer to a separate aligned area as woolstar recommends.  Alternatively, you could write a class putting the buffer at 4096-aligned memory and having placing the other data members immediately after that, perhaps with a `struct extras { int thr_cnt, indv_cnt' }; extras& get_extras() { return *(extras*)(p_mem_buff + XX); }`.

Comment: yes, as I told you previously it was a separate piece of memory from the struct, I have just added structu since I needed to pass arguments to the CreateThread process and since we can only assign one argument, hence I am using the struct.
Previously with this same technique(struct as an argument) when I was passing the other two elements, i.e. thr_cnt and indv_cnt, and keeping memory alignemnt as global, I had the data mismatch problem coming from DMA and storing to file, i.e. data of file 5 was getting re-stored in file-6. Hence I think I should go this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a DLL and you are compiling with MSVC / Visual C++, you can explicitly align the struct members:

```
struct g_thread_param {
int thr_cnt ; 
int indv_cnt ;
__declspec(align(4096)) char mem_buff[XX];
} ;
```

Comment: thanks, I found out that it does not support alignment for 4096 bytes alignment :(

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, alignment up to 8192 is supported - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx. What kind of error do you get, and what compiler version do you use?

Comment: Error 1 error C2719: 'T1': formal parameter with __declspec(align('4096')) won't be aligned e:\coding\cpp\share_mem_with_struct\share_mem_with_struct\sh_mem_w_strcut.cpp 14 1 share_mem_with_struct
....
....
Note that I am doing folloing as test case
__declspec(align(4096)) char mem_buff[80000];

Comment: Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/373ak2y1%28VS.71%29.aspx), you are likely passing this struct as a value parameter to some method, the compiler cannot align it on the stack (or so I vaguely remember). Pass it to your method by pointer or const ref instead.

Comment: oh yes...that solves my isseu. Now I will try to implement the learning on my actual code...
thanks

Comment: and one more thing...It's scope is local to the function it is called, right?
It is because, it is not normal memory allocation, infact it is making a strcut class, where among other elements I have assigned some memory for my use, in the heap. Hence how can I destroy that memory, since I will pass that struct class from main to the other threads.

Comment: I am not really clear on the question, but it is a normal memory allocation, so all the usual rules apply including considerations of sharing memory among different threads. Maybe it'd be best to phrase your problem as a separate question with an explicit example. Cheers!